# Facebook Graph API: Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to load the feed from a popular group which I am the admin of. To do so I am using the Graph API explorer at `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`.

The URL is to get the group feed is `<group-id>/feed`. When I test this with a much smaller group I am part of, it works as expected and I get 25 of the most recent posts in the group.

However with this busy group, I get a message saying

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request"
  }
}
```

As is suggested elsewhere, I adding a limit of 1 to my request, yet the error is still the same!

`<group-id>/feed?limit=1`

Does anyone have any other suggestions how to get this data?

Comment: If this is reproducible, file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: A suggestion I've seen elsewhere is to also try the `since` and `until` parameters.